# ExpressJS - How to change the value of key in the url of a get request

Tags: node.js, express, pagination

So I am developing custom pagination functionality with express and mongoose. I have a get parameter called page and I need to change the value for every different page. The problem is that the way I do it it keeps appending "page" key-value pairs to the url like this "&page=1&page=1&page=1". That is because I don't simply change the value of "page" but I append the key-value pair each time like so:

```
currentPageUrl: req.originalUrl + '&page=' + currentPage
```

I need just to change the value of the "page" key. How can I accomplish this? Any advice, express helper function or custom solution would help a lot. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the `page=xxx` param is already there, you can use `.replace()`:

```
currentPageUrl: req.originalUrl.replace(/page=[^&]+/, "page=" + currentPage)
```

If you don't know for sure whether it is there, then you have to test for it first:

```
let newUrl;
if (req.originalUrl.indexOf("page=") !== -1) {
    newUrl = req.originalUrl.replace(/page=[^&]+/, "page=" + currentPage);
} else if (req.originalUrl.indexOf("?") === -1) {
    newUrl = req.originalUrl + "?page=" + currentPage);
} else {
    newUrl = req.originalUrl + "&page=" + currentPage);
}
```

Various test cases:

```js
function updatePage(origUrl, currentPage) {
    let newUrl;
    if (origUrl.indexOf("page=") !== -1) {
        newUrl = origUrl.replace(/page=[^&]+/, "page=" + currentPage);
    } else if (origUrl.indexOf("?") === -1) {
        newUrl = origUrl + "?page=" + currentPage;
    } else {
        newUrl = origUrl + "&page=" + currentPage;
    }
    return newUrl;
}

// test cases
console.log(updatePage("http://somedomain.com/somePath?page=3", 5));
console.log(updatePage("http://somedomain.com/somePath?whatever=something&page=3", 5));
console.log(updatePage("http://somedomain.com/somePath", 5));
console.log(updatePage("http://somedomain.com/somePath?page=3&whatever=something", 5));
```

---

You could also use the `url` library to parse the URL into its parts, change one part, then regenerate the full URL:

```
 const url = require('url');

 let parsedUrl = url.parse(req.originalUrl, true);
 parsedUrl.query.page = currentPage;
 delete parsedUrl.search;
 let newUrl = url.format(parsedUrl);
```

Comment: I think this works fine in my case. Thanks for helping out man!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function that takes a url, a parameter and the new value you want it to be. I think this does exactly what you want

```
const url = require('url')

uri = 'http://example.com/cat?page=1&rand=18347109823'

function change_parameter(uri, parameter_name, new_value){
  parsed_uri = url.parse(uri, true)
  parameters = []
  for ( key in parsed_uri.query ) {
    if ( key == parameter_name ) {
      parameters.push( key + "=" + new_value )
    } else {
      parameters.push( key + "=" + parsed_uri.query[key] )
    }
  }
  return parsed_uri.protocol + "//" + parsed_uri.hostname + "?" + parameters.join("&")
}

console.log(change_parameter(uri, 'page', '3'))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$ node so.js 
http://example.com?page=3&rand=18347109823
```

Comment: Thanks for your time writing this function! I tested it out and it works. However it doesn't work when your url is something like http://example.com/animals/list/param1=5&page=3&type=dog.
It makes /animals/list to /null/null/ and it stops working.

Comment: @Codearts Definitely, I assumed that `page` is a url get parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try using the URL library. Refer to this page. https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost

You can tweak your url however you would like to.

So in your case I would get `url.origin` and `url.pathname` but it would depend on what you want to get.